# OpenCV 3.0 SVM Assertion Error using Python

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I'm using the Python OpenCV wrapper and I want to implement a simple classifier using a SVM. 
At first I create an matrix filled with zeros which has a shape of:

```
np.zeros( (len(positives)+len(negatives), samples_height*samples_width), dtype = np.float32)
```

After that I load all positive and negative samples as a row into the matrix:

```
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir("svm_data/positives")):
    image = cv2.imread("svm_data/positives/"+file, 0)
    traindata[i,:] = np.ravel(image)
    labels.append(0)

for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir("svm_data/negatives")):
    image = cv2.imread("svm_data/negatives/"+file, 0)
    traindata[positives+i,:] = np.ravel(image)
    labels.append(1)
```

Finally I setup the SVM:

```
self.svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
self.svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
self.svm.setGamma(0.5)
self.svm.setC(30)
self.svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR)
self.svm.train(traindata, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, np.array(labels, dtype = np.int32))
self.svm.save('svm.dat')
```

*Btw. it seems that svm.load ist not implemented yet.*

But now if I want to test my trained SVM with an image from my positives folder (or any other image) by calling:

```
image = np.float32(cv2.imread("svm_data/positives/158_233_486.png", 0))
print self.svm.predict(np.ravel(image))
```

The program will terminate and throw

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict

I read a few posts which answers "The error means, that the input image does not have the same size or type like the samples" but the output of:

```
    print traindata[i,:].shape
    print traindata[i,:].dtype

    print np.ravel(image).shape
    print np.ravel(image).dtype
```

is

```
(1681,)
float32
(1681,)
float32
```

and now I'm very confused and I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks

---------------- UPDATE ----------------

It seems that there is a problem with the shape of my sample matrix.
I added a few prints above the line 1930 in svm.cpp

```
printf("samples.cols: %d\n", samples.cols);
printf("var_count: %d\n", var_count);
printf("samples.type(): %d\n", samples.type());
printf("CV_32F: %d\n", CV_32F);

CV_Assert( samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F );
```

After a OpenCV rebuild my output was:

```
samples.cols: 1
var_count: 1681
samples.type(): 5
CV_32F: 5

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict, file opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1938
```

---------------- UPDATE ----------------

Ok I've got it!

```
image = np.float32(cv2.imread("svm_data/positives/158_233_486.png", 0))
print self.svm.predict(np.ravel(image))
```

The loaded image is a 1xn matrix but svm predict expect in my case a nx1 array, 
 so this fixes for me :)

```
print self.svm.predict(np.ravel(image)[None, :])
```

Comment: "Btw. it seems that svm.load ist not implemented yet." - please update your opencv repo, this was fixed a few days ago.

Comment: Ok nice! But yesterday I cloned https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/ completely new and checked out "3.1.0" after cmake, make and make install python also answered "3.1.0" after calling cv2.__version__. Do I need another repo?

Comment: Now I used 'git pull origin master' and my head is #1cd3c6f which seems to be the latest, but even after a rebuild I got the Python error: 'cv2.ml_SVM' object has no attribute 'load' ...